# Passing params in Spoon (Pentaho) Transformation by command line

Tags: cmd, parameters, pentaho, spoon

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) 8.1. I'm trying to passing parameters to a transformation using the command line. I'm using the sample writeback.ktr. This is my line:

```
java -jar launcher\launcher.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan -initialDir "C:\Users\Sistemas\Documents\Pentaho-Data-Integration"\ -file:"C:\Users\Sistemas\Documents\Pentaho-Data-Integration\samples\trans\writeback.ktr" -param="arg1=Boris" -param="arg2=Pedro" -param="arg3=Cristian" -level:Minimal
```

But it keeps creating the file without the values I'm passing to. I'm also try these other ways:

```
-param:"arg1=Boris"
-param:arg1=Boris
```

[image]

I'm using this configuration. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me please

Thanks

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 64 bits

Comment: You want to execute your transformation using command prompt right ?

Comment: Yep... as a starting point. We dont want to have a client open Pentaho to run some transformation. So we want to provide a front end, but first, we are trying to pass some params to our transformation by command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample:

```
pan.bat /file:C:\Pentaho_samples\repository\repository_export.kjb
    "/param:rep_name=PDI2000" "/param:rep_user=admin" "/param:rep_password=password"
    "/param:rep_folder=/public/dev"
    "/param:target_filename=C:\Pentaho_samples\repository\export\dev.xml"
```

Check below link for more clarification.
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Command_Line_Tools

Comment: I dont get it... it doesn't work. I followed your solution. It should works, but still doesnt. I included a picture with the transformation, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This is my new sentence: `pan.bat -file:C:\Users\Sistemas\Documents\Pentaho-Data-Integration\samples\trans\writeback.ktr "-param:arg1=PDI2000" "-param:arg2=admin" "-param:arg3=password"`

Comment: The file is created with this content: 
`
arg1;arg2;arg3
;;
`

Answer (score 1):

Well... after trying different alternatives, finally got a solution:

```
pan.bat -file:C:\trans\writeback.ktr "PDI2000" "admin"
```

This way, my transformation took the parameters.

Thanks.